# Redirect function stops working after I implemented an AJAX function for the Post request

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, google-app-engine, webapp2

After I make a POST to the GAE, I want to render the HTML page that will display the data I just posted.  Thus in the POST request, at the end, I call a GET request with the entity ID.  It worked until I implemented the POST request with AJAX request (rather than just an HTML form), but now it won't work.
This is the request that isn't working: `self.redirect('/house/%s' % str(p.key.id()))`. My intuition says that it is because I'm am calling this from an AJAX function on the client side, and it is trying to go to a new page before that AJAX function is done.  However, I'm not very good at JS or Python, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!  A terminal is responding this:

```
Magikarp uses Splash. It's not very effective.
INFO     2017-10-24 04:03:00,931 module.py:832] default: "POST /house HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2017-10-24 04:03:00,994 module.py:832] default: "GET /house/4554452040123423436 HTTP/1.1" 200 3024

def post(self):
        if not self.user:
            self.redirect('/home')
        data = json.loads(self.request.body)
        city = data["city"]
        state = data["state"]
        jsObject = data["jsObject"]
        if city and state:
            p = Post(parent = blog_key(), city = city, state = state, jsObject = jsObject)
            p.put()
            print ("Magikarp uses Splash. It's not very effective.")
            self.redirect('/house/%s' % str(p.key.id()))
        else:
            error = "city and state, please!"
            self.render("newhouse.html", city=city, state=state, error=error)

function postRequest() {
    var city = $("#city").val();
    var state = $("#state").val();
    var jsObject = JSObject;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/submit",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "city": city,
            "state": state,
            "jsObject": jsObject  
        }),
        dataType: "json"
    })
        .done(function(jsonResponse) {
            $("#error").html(jsonResponse.message);
        });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it won't work`? What's your `get()` code for the redirection url?

Comment: it won't work as in; it use to redirect to the page house/4554452040123423436 and that would be my house "template" with the information of houseid=4554452040123423436 passed in.  Now it doesn't redirect from the page where I submit the data.  
def get(self, post_id):
        key1 = ndb.Key('Post', int(post_id), parent=blog_key())
        post = key1.get()

        if not post:
            self.error(404)
            return

        self.render("permalink.html", post = post)

Comment: Generally AJAX is used when no page navigation is needed. Any specific reason for you to use AJAX instead of the HTML form, which according to you is working perfectly fine??

Comment: the whole point of ajax is to avoid page refreshes, navigation, postbacks etc. Ajax clients don't automatically follow redirect headers returned by the server (like a browser would in a traditional postback) for precisely this reason. If you need to redirect after the POST, then a traditional postback is more suitable, no need for ajax.

Comment: The reason I was using AJAX was because I need to send a javascript object...and am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do that through a html form?  Any tips?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects